# subjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled only works on certain camera devices

Tags: ios, camera, avcapturedevice

I've been attempting to use `AVCaptureDevice`'s `subjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled` property to monitor movement with a potential motion-detection application.

For the back-facing camera of both iPhone 4S and iPad 2, I receive `AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification`s when I would expect to, however on both devices, when I attempt to enable this on the front-facing camera, I receive no notifications at all.

Why doesn't this work on the front-facing cameras?

Answer (score 0):

According to an Apple engineer in this [Developer Forums response](https://devforums.apple.com/message/707449#707449), this is expected behaviour:

> subjectAreaChangeMonitoring is meant to tell you if the scene has changed enough that it's probably out of focus, so you should refocus.  Consequently, the feature only works on cameras that support focus.

So you cannot rely on this API for motion detection, at least for the front-facing cameras.